# Spine and rest of rig won't work together- Any solutions?

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones

I recently made a rig of a model, but after some posing tests, I decided it needs an additional spine collum, as can be seen in the image. I tried multiple times to make the spine and other chest/torso sections work together, but nothing seemed to work. Is it possible to make it so that when the chest and torso move, the spine moves with it, keeping its bendy bone properties?

[image: Spine and rig]

Comment: You can create an IK bone at the top of the spine so that it controls the rest of the bone chain?